# MySQL display rows with timestamp less than 07:00

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my SQL database that has values like 1:00 (meaning 1 AM), 13:56 (1:56 PM), etc. I would like to have the mysql command show only the variables after 7 AM. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your column is named `theTime`, in a table named `foo`:

```
select * from foo where HOUR(theTime) >= 7;
```

If your column is not a date/time or timestamp field, you are in some trouble.